# How to set CPU Frequency in IAR Embedded workbench?

Tags: arm, embedded, keil, iar, atmelstudio

I want to set the CPU(XTAL) frequency for my microcontroller(LPC2129) in IAR Embedded Workbench IDE, but after lots of search and exploration in IDE, I nowhere found anything related to it. Maybe my question looks so general but it happens to me. Every Embedded IDE/compiler(like Keil, Mikroc, ATMEL Studio) has this CPU frequency set option but in IAR I not know how to set it. Sometimes, I am also guessing that if there is no option in software than there must be some compiler-specific keyword like F_CPU(in ATMEL Studio ) must be there.
Please help..Thank you

Comment: Setting clock speeds can be done by programming various registers. Read the CPU manual for details

Comment: I know that..anyway thank you, sir

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the IAR EW for the LPC2129 so far (only for STM32) but since IAR doesn't provide any HAL on their own there are no options in the IDE to set the frequency for your project.

This settings depends on you used HAL (either in a config.h file of directly in the startup code)